# dedicate/devote money/time to sth

Tags: word-usage

According to the OALD, both *dedicate and devote* can be used in the sense of "giving your time/money/effort to something". So are the following sentences correct?

**The US government’s budget [dedicated/devoted] to space research was 6.5 billion dollars in 1980.**

**4 hours every week were [dedicated/devoted] to playing video games by an average US citizen under the age of 15 in 2013.**

Answer (score 2):

These two verbs *devoted* and *dedicated* seem to be associated with important and meaningful tasks.  Hence I won't use them on the video games example.  I would say

> Four hours every week were [spent playing] video games by an average US citizen under the age of 15 in 2013.

As for the other example, both verbs are possible.  However, I would choose [*allocated*, which is more common than *devoted* or *dedicated*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=budget+allocated%2Cbudget+devoted%2Cbudget+dedicated&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3):

> The US government’s budget [allocated] to space research was 6.5 billion dollars in 1980.